# Remove everything outside of body tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable which contains responseText from an external HTML page:

```
textFromFile = myRequest.responseText;
```

How could i delete everything **outside** of the body tags?
I can delete all the HTML tags in the string (**textFromFile**) using Regex but before i do that, i would appreciate if someone could help me with removing all the characters outside of the body tags (in other words, just keep the strings/ words within the body tags of the HTML page).

----**Edited part**----

The HTML file that I am reading in is:

```
<html>
<head> title </head>
<body>
<p> Hello World! <br/>
<a href = ”link.html”> Click <b> here </b> </a> <br/>
Goodbye world!
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When i apply:

```
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(myRequest.responseText, "text/html");
            alert(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

The response is:

```
title 

<p> Hello World! <br>
<a href="”link.html”"> Click <b> here </b> </a> <br>
Goodbye world!
</p>
```

Which shouldn't be the case as 'title' is outside of the body tags.

Comment: There are only two elements "outside" the body: the HTML parent element and head sibling element. Why not just get the outerHTML of the body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a DOM parser to parse the HTML:

```
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(myRequest.responseText, "text/html");
```

And then simply use `innerHTML` (or `outerHTML`):

```
doc.body.innerHTML;
```

```js
var string = "<!DOCTYPE html><title>Title</title><p>Hello</p>",
    doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(string, "text/html");
document.getElementById('inner').textContent = doc.body.innerHTML;
document.getElementById('outer').textContent = doc.body.outerHTML;
```

```css
pre {
  background: #ddd;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
The inner HTML of &lt;body&gt; is:
<pre id="inner"></pre>
The outer HTML of &lt;body&gt; is:
<pre id="outer"></pre>
```

Comment: I've applied that but it still prints out the other parts e.g. the <head> title </head>

Comment: @NewToCoding Can you provide an example of that response? If you run the code snippet in my anwer, you will see it should work.

Comment: I've added the response (shown below 'edited part' in my question) @Oriol

Comment: @NewToCoding OK, I see. This is expected. Since `head` can't contain content, if you place content there, browsers will close the `head` automatically and begin the `body`.

Comment: I was wondering the same because it's supposed to be placed in the title tag but i guess it's intentionally placed there. Thanks for the help - I'll accept the answer. :) @Oriol

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just uses string replace function with some RegExp():

Try this:

```
var responseText = "<html>\
<head> title </head>\
<body>\
<p> Hello World! <br/>\
<a href = ”link.html”> Click <b> here </b> </a> <br/>\
Goodbye world!\
</p>\
</body>\
</html>";

console.log(responseText.replace(new RegExp(".*(<body>)(.*)(<\/body>).*", 'gm'), "$1$2$3"));
```

**OUTPUT:**

`<body><p> Hello World! <br/><a href = ”link.html”> Click <b> here </b> </a> <br/>Goodbye world!</p></body>`

From above remove $1 and $3 if you don't want to include **<body>** and **</body>** tag

Comment: This could work but it requires a lot of manual input to get the exact output i would need whereas the accepted answer (above) is more efficient. It does exactly what i need without the hassle although it doesn't cover the unexpected input (e.g. having characters in the header tag). Your answer is perfect in the case the HTML was poorly written but i've solved the issue in my HTML file so parsing worked. :)

Comment: It [*shouldn't have to be said*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)…